# CICoreMLModelFilter throws "Unsupported engine type"

Tags: swift, core-graphics, core-image, coreml

There's this new and still undocumented `CICoreMLModelFilter` within CoreImage. It takes two parameters:

> **inputImage** - The image to use as an input image. For filters that also use a background image, this is the foreground image.
>
> **inputModel** - The CoreML model to be used for applying effect on the image.

The idea is pretty simple - take an image, apply style transfer and spit out stylized image.

So I loaded CoreML Model into my test application and tried to pass this model as `inputModel` key:

```
guard
    let mlFilter = CIFilter(name: "CICoreMLModelFilter")
else {
    return nil
}

let model = StarryStyle().model

mlFilter.setValue(workingImage, forKey: "inputImage")
mlFilter.setValue(model, forKey: "inputModel")

guard
    let mlResult = mlFilter.outputImage
else {
    return nil
}
```

Whenever I try to run this very simple code I get the following exception:

```
[Espresso::handle_ex_] exception=Unsupported engine type
```

Regardless of MLModel I try to load, it always throws with the exception above. I'm running Swift 4.2 on Mojave (10.14).

Did anyone try to play with CoreImage and CoreML?

Comment: What you're trying to do is probably totally unsupported, but Espresso is the thing that actually runs Core ML models. The "engine type" can be MPS (for using the GPU), ANE (for the new neural engine on the A12), and possibly others. It would be interesting to see what the actual engine type is that is being requested here. Are you running this on an iPhone XS? If not, that might be the explanation.

Comment: Matthijs, thanks for your input but I respectfully disagree. It is perfectly possible to do just that as this has been shown on this WWDC session https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/719 (43:20). They loaded CoreML model and passed it to `CICoreMLModelFilter ` to achieve style transfer.

Comment: Ah, but if they showed it WWDC then it's not really undocumented. ;-) Did they show it on Mojave on WWDC or on a phone?

Comment: I just tested the filter with my models and it actually works (on an iPhone X). However, it leaks a lot of memory with every call to `outputImage` and after a few frames the app runs out of memory. It also uses scale-to-fit on the input image to match the model's input size—no smart scaling and cropping as Vision does. I guess you are better off writing your own `CIImageProcessorKernel` for integrating CoreML models into Core Image.

Answer (score 2):

Im running into this error on Mac OS 10.14 - on a model that works fine on iOS 12 sans errors, and on earlier versions of Mac OS - 10.13. Initially I thought this was related to floating point quantization, but ive tried this on non quantized float 32 models, and on different devices, and get it for models that:

- Output / run inference fine
- Use standard CoreML / Vision API's
- Run on integrated or discreet GPUs
- on iMac Pro AMD GPUs
- on MBP Nvidia GPUs

im not sure if this is just some internal exception that's handled - on AMD, I get a slightly different error ;

`[Espresso:handle_ex_] exception=<private>`

Im beginning to think it's innocuous?

Answer (score 1):

Adding an interesting answer/discovery because the error message is the same, but I am not using anything related to the `CoreML` API (or so I thought).

> WatchKit Extension[7896:536979] [espresso] [Espresso::handle_ex_] exception=Unsupported engine type

I am getting this message when I am using the text input controller. Specifically `presentTextInputController`.

[image]

I believe this is simply appearing because the CoreML engine is running on the simulator. *At least in the case of the `text input controller` this is the apparent reason for this message.*

The text input controller which is a controller we get for free, includes the Scribble text input. It's obviously discreetly piggybacking on the same CoreML engine otherwise it wouldn't be able to recognize scribbles.

There is no way to disable Scribble input to actually test this theory. Dictation and Scribble are enabled by default. You can only disable `emoji` and/or `animatedEmoji`. But it is pretty evident this is what is happening.